# How to drag only one corner of an image view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I try to implement one feature of a photo editing app.I do not have any clue to implement this that's why I share some photo to explain my question.the normal picture looks like this.

[image]
when I click the lower right corner of the image and dragging it down it only expand that part and the new image looks like this.

[image]

And if I do the reverse the picture look like this.

[image]

so the question is which gesture actually support this kind of dragging and how to implement this? For batter understanding you can see [manly](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/manly-photo-editor-for-men/id1263326810?mt=8) app which implement this in there abs section.

Comment: A few things. First, a quick search on GitHub for "resizable view" yields a few examples including this one (https://github.com/RajatJain4061/RKUserResizableView). Be aware though - this will only get you part way there, as all `UIViews` consist of a `CGRect` which always has two parallel sides. All these "resizable views" can do is help you to use a *pan gesture* with *grab handles*. From there you'll need to probably do some drawing with `UIBezierPaths` and (maybe) `CAShapeLayers`. And if you wish to crop such a shape? Look into `CIPerspectiveCorrection` and CoreImage. Good luck!

Comment: Why do you have both Swift and Objective-C tags? What language are you using? Remove the tag for the other language so if anybody posts code, it's in your preferred language (unless you're "bilingual" and really are happy with either, but I'm guessing that if you were fluent in both languages you wouldn't be asking for help with such a straightforward problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DuncanC.I missed it and learn from you but why you try  to judge me?I am not expert but understand both language that's why giving both tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So think it through. If you grab the lower right corner and start dragging, you need to not just change the location of that corner, but also change the X position of the top right, and the Y position of the bottom left corner, so the resulting shape is always a rectangle.

Alternately, you can use a CGRect instead of a random quadrilateral, and then simply figure out which of the rect's properties you need to change for each corner (for the lower right corner you just edit the height and width. For the top right, you have to change the height, width, and `origin.y`. for the top left, you need to change the height, width, `origin.x`, and `origin.y`. For the bottom left you need to change the height, width, and `origin.x`.

You also need to think about what to do if the user drags the rectangle to zero size, or past zero so that the corners cross and the corner that was the bottom left is now the top right. Do you allow that, or do you just limit the dragging so it can't be dragged smaller than some minimum size? Either approach is valid, but you need to think it through, code it, and test it.

This isn't that hard, and it's nuts-and-bolts graphics programming. You'd learn a lot by doing it yourself rather than using a third-party framework.